# Anonymous functions pre PHP 5.3.0

Tags: php, anonymous-function

Is there an alternative to anonymous functions in versions of PHP previous to 5.3.0?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is [create_function](http://php.net/create_function) but it generally isn't recommended. If you're using OOP, you'd be better off defining a one-off private member to use with a callback instead.

Comment: Also, the result of create_function will not be garbage collected. So it's basically a memory leak.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, [`create_function()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.create-function.php)

Answer (score 2):

There are two choices.

First is to create a function, inside a function. Unfortunately, it will pollute the global namespace.

The second choice is to use
[create_function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.create-function.php).

Comment: That wouldn't make the inner function an anonymous function... just a function declared inside a function.

Comment: Plus, the "inner" function won't be a closure.