# PHP Anonymous functions

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Anonymous functions pre PHP 5.3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3694620/anonymous-functions-pre-php-5-3-0)

Hello,

How could I do

```
$ar = array_filter($ar, function($el) {
    $search = 'New York';
    $name = $ar['name'];
    $potentialNumber = substr($name, strlen($search));
    return ((substr($name, 0, strlen($search)) == $search) && // starts with NY
            ($potentialNumber == '' || is_numeric($potentialNumber)); // [0-9]*
});
```

Before PHP 5.3?

Comment: am out of closevotes but definite duplicate of [Anonymous functions pre-PHP 5.3.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3694620/anonymous-functions-pre-php-5-3-0)

Comment: *(reference)* [Callbacks in the PHP Language](http://de2.php.net/manual/en/language.pseudo-types.php#language.types.callback)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Closest would be to use `create_function` to mimic lambda functions http://php.net/manual/en/function.create-function.php

Answer (score 0):

As you're aware, you can't use anonymous functions/closures before 5.3, so the sensible solution would be to define a function (either through the use of [create_function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.create-function.php) or normally) within the local scope of the function/method that you're currently in.

Answer (score 0):

The way it is shown in example #1 in here : http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php

Answer (score 0):

Just use a callback.

```
$ar = array_filter($ar, "myFunction");

function myFunction($el) {
    $search = 'New York';
    $name = $ar['name'];
    $potentialNumber = substr($name, strlen($search));
    return ((substr($name, 0, strlen($search)) == $search) && // starts with NY
            ($potentialNumber == '' || is_numeric($potentialNumber)); // [0-9]*
}
```

If you're in a class instead of global code, the callback passed to array_filter should be `array(this, 'myFunction')`