# Code working only PHP 5.3.6

Tags: php, version

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Anonymous functions pre PHP 5.3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3694620/anonymous-functions-pre-php-5-3-0)

I have this code:

```
$bbcode = 'Users [user=1], [user=2] and [user=3] are friendly.';
echo preg_replace_callback(
            '#\[user=(\d+)\]#',
            function($matches) {
                $userName = getUserNameByUserId($matches[1]);
                return "<a href=user.php?id=$matches[1]>$userName</a>";
            },
            $bbcode
        );
```

And it's working only for the last PHP version. I want to make it work for PHP 5.2.17.

Comment: Instead of duplicating it on PHP 5.2, you could of course also define a normal function. Which seems more appropriate in this case.

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can:

```
function callback_function($matches) {
  $userName = getUserNameByUserId($matches[1]);
  return "<a href=user.php?id=$matches[1]>$userName</a>";
}

$bbcode = 'Users [user=1], [user=2] and [user=3] are friendly.';
echo preg_replace_callback(
            '#\[user=(\d+)\]#',
            'callback_function',
            $bbcode
);
```

The function needs to be defined slightly different for PHP 5.2.x, so define it prior calling pre_replace_callback. Then provide it's name in form of a string.

Probably you can additionally upgrade the PHP version on the host where you want to run the code. PHP 5.3 is much faster then PHP 5.2 which is out of live even.

Answer (score 0):

Anonymous functions were introduced in version 5.3, so that code will only work in 5.3 and up.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a much simpler construction:

```
echo "Users ";
echo "<a href=\"user.php?id=1\">" . getUserNameByUserId(1) . "</a>";
echo ", ";
echo "<a href=\"user.php?id=2\">" . getUserNameByUserId(2) . "</a>";
echo " and ";
echo "<a href=\"user.php?id=3\">" . getUserNameByUserId(3) . "</a>";
echo " are friendly.";
```

Comment: Well, that was just an example. I use this for Private Messages betwen users. If there are 1000 PM's, I can't write the code for each of them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the 'e' option of preg_replace as an alternative.

```
echo preg_replace('#\[user=(\d+)\]#e','"<a href=\"user.php?id=$1".getUserNameByUserId($1)."</a>"',$bbcode);
```